# How do user drag the pin location to another location, and making the GPS take this new coordinated. In swift

Tags: ios, swift, gps, geolocation

I would like that the User would be able to drag the location of pin up another street, and so the application would take these new locations.

Code Below:

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please use the answers section for answers only. While you may [answer your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), your code sample belongs in the question itself. I recommend you delete your answer below and edit your question to include the sample.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Function to manage the location of the User
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    let location:CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location!.coordinate
    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation() // Stop location

    print("location = \(location.latitude)\(location.latitude)")

    latitude = location.latitude
    longitude = location.longitude

    let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D (latitude: location.latitude, longitude: location.longitude)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.01, 0.01))

    self.map.setRegion(region, animated: true)

    self.map.removeAnnotations(map.annotations)

    let pinLocation: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.latitude, location.longitude)
    let pinAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    pinAnnotation.coordinate = pinLocation
    pinAnnotation.title = "Você"

    self.map.addAnnotation(pinAnnotation)


    //Funcao para pegar a localizacao e transformar em nome
    let requestCLLocation = CLLocation(latitude: self.latitude, longitude: self.longitude)
    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(requestCLLocation, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error) -> Void in

        if (error != nil){
            print(error!)
        }else{
            if placemarks!.count > 0 {
                let p = CLPlacemark(placemark: (placemarks?[0])! as CLPlacemark)



                var locationName = p.addressDictionary!["Name"] as? NSString
                var bairro = p.addressDictionary!["SubLocality"] as? NSString
                var city = p.addressDictionary!["City"] as? NSString
                var state = p.addressDictionary!["State"] as? NSString

                if (locationName == nil){
                    locationName = "Rua não encontrada"
                }

                if (bairro == nil){
                    bairro = "Bairro não encontrado"
                }

                if (city == nil){
                    city = "Cidade não encontrada"
                }

                if (state == nil){
                    state = "Erro"
                }


                //Street name in Label
                self.streetName.text = ((locationName!) as String)+", "+((bairro!) as String)+", "+((city!) as String)+"-"+((state!) as String)

            }
        }})


}
```